# A group in which every proper subgroup is contained in a maximal subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group in which every proper subgroup is contained in a maximal subgroup of $G$.

Can we conclude that $G$ is finitely generated? (@Max commented that converse of this statement is true.)

Comment: You must mean every *proper* subgroup is contained in a maximal subgroup. How about a direct product of countably many groups of prime order $p$? The quotient group with any subgroup has the same property and has maximal subgroups.

Comment: The converse *is* true : in a finitely generated group, every proper subgroup is contained in a maximal subgroup (hint : given a finite generating family $F$, a subgroup of $G$ is $G$ iff it contains $F$)

Comment: @Max: So I completely misremember :) I did not really understand your hint. But I thought the following. Let $H<G$ and let $\mathfrak L$ be the set of all proper subgroups of $G$ that contains $H$. Assume that $\mathfrak L$ does not have a maximal element. Then there exists a totoally ordered set $\mathbb S$ such that $\bigcup_{H\in S}H\notin \mathfrak L$, and hence $\bigcup_{H\in S}H=G$. Since $G$ is finitly generated, $G\in \mathbb S$. This is a contradiction as $G$ is not proper in $G$.

Comment: How do you deduce $G\in S$ ?

Comment: @Max:  $G$ is finitely generated, that is $\langle x_1,x_2,...,x_k\rangle=G$. As $\bigcup_{H\in \mathbb S}H=G$, set $x_i\in H_i$. Then $G=H_j$ for some $j$. Thus, $G\in \mathbb S$.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it (and that's what my hint was about)

Comment: @Max: What is finite generating family?

Comment: A finite family that generates $G$

Comment: Anyway Max, I did not understand what you mean. According to you, what I did is exactly what your hint is, So it is ok. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No.  For instance, let $G$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{F}_p$ for some prime $p$.  Then every proper subgroup (i.e., subspace) is contained in a maximal subgroup (i.e., codimension 1 subspace) but $G$ is not finitely generated unless it is finite dimensional.

Answer (score 2):

It will work when the number of maximal subgroups is finite. Then we can assume that $M_1, \dots M_n$ are all maximal subgroups in $G$. There exists $x_i \notin M_i$ as each $M_i$ is a maximal subgroup ($M_i$ is a proper subgroup of $G$). Now the group generated by $x_i$ is not contained in any of $M_i$, thus should not be a proper subgroup because of the assumption. As a result, we have:
$$ \langle x_1, x_2, \dots,x_n \rangle = G $$
We will have such a condition; for example, when all of the maximal subgroups are finite index and conjugate to each other.